# What are the proper steps to replace a poorly installed dryer vent in an old flat roof in Phoenix?

Tags: exhaust-fan, roofing, flashing

The dryer vent extends from a utility wall in the center of the house directly up and through the roof.  The current penetration is a simple hole with a dome screen topped by a vent hood.

I believe the roof is a foam rolled roof.  It's white.

It's horribly inefficient and causes pretty heavy static pressure.  So much, in fact, that I discovered that a majority of the exhausted air from the dryer simply bounces back from the exterior vent hood and blows right back into the ceiling joist cavity where the insulation sits.  Bad.  Moisture, heat...potential mold, etc.

So, I want to free up the bottleneck by replacing the vent hood that's there with a new one.

Facts:

Flat roof.
Penetration already exists.

If I were to remove the current hood and flashing by cutting it out, I would have exposed plywood.  It's from that point that I'm not certain of the materials I need to use to restore the surface of the roof after installing a new flashing and hood.

Any insight would be appreciated.

This image is in no way to scale, but rather for illustration.  The red shows where the air is being forced, and the blue is where the air should be going.

[image: Illustration]

Comment: can you explain better or provide a picture on how the air 
"bounces back" and gets into the ceiling? I don't see how that could happen without a hole in the duct, which basically precludes the whole question with an obvious answer.

Comment: How many feet does the air have to travel to get from the dryer to the roof? Can you route it through an exterior wall instead? See [M1502.6 Duct length.](https://www.nachi.org/dryer-vent-safety.htm)

Comment: Unfortunately, the exterior wall is not an option.  The vent starts at about 40" above the ground (stacked dryer) and goes nearly straight up to the flat roof which is only about 5 more feet.

Comment: Imagine a 4" vent pipe sticking through the roof.  Above that is a screen in the shape of a dome.  Above that is a vent hood.  That's it.  The 4" vent pipe is inserted into the penetration through the roof and rests just below the screen.  One would think that the air would simply blow through the screen and out the hood, but there's a ton of static pressure which forces the air back down around the outside edge of the vent pipe and back into the cavity between the roof and the insulation.

Comment: Is the screen clogged with lint? Overall it looks like a poorly designed dryer vent for the roof. Do you have the means to replace it?

Comment: The screen really isn't that blocked.  It's just a poorly designed vent and always has been, but I didn't know it because...well, who opens up their roof?  ;).  Yes, I have the means, that's why I asked the question in the first place.  Before I go ripping out the old one, I need to know what materials I'll need to restore the roof and properly install the flashing.